# facebook graph api - pages - not getting images in the posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api

when I am requesting posts from public facebook pages. I get all the messages in text but not getting any image which is there in the posts.

[image]

Have attached screenshot for the reference. The page which i have used is,

```
https://www.facebook.com/bbcnews/
```

and it's id is 228735667216

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s called "Declarative Fields", see changelog. You have to specify the fields you want to get returned:

```
/page-id/posts?fields=message,picture,full_picture,...
```

Existing fields: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/post

Comment: Hey, thanks. it worked for me. but getting pictures of size 130 pixels. Is there a way where i can get larger image or actual size image?

Comment: Great. Thank you so much.